# Submit button with Options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

For one form, I want to have two submit buttons , named:

`Appove`, `Decline`

when the user clicks on `Approve` it should send `approve: true` as well

when the user clicks on `Decline` it should send `approve: false` as well

**Basically the buttons should work like a checkbox**

Is this possible with Rails and how to implement it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but you need js/jquery for this. You will have hidden checkbox that you will check in proper way and two buttons.
Lets assume that your form has id 'form'. And you checkbox has id 'approve_checkbox'
In this case you need [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) function for something like this.

```
$('#approve_button').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#approve_checkbox').prop('checked', true);
  $('#form').submit();
});

$('#decline_button').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#approve_checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  $('#form').submit();
});
```

Of course you can simplify this code, but I think idea is clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the standard `submit` form helper, you will get returned a param with the key "commit".   You can test for this in your controller code.

```
<%= f.submit 'Approve' %>
<%= f.submit 'Decline' %>
```

in the controller...

```
def create
  approved = params[:commit] == 'Approve'
```

The `approved` variable will then contain true or false and you can use it as needed in the rest of the action / method.

Comment: This is very easy to implement but this is bad approach. Because it relies on button text...

Comment: You can change the `name` value for the button but then the challenge is you find that you have to test for presence of a key...

Comment: so `params[:approvet]` or `params [:decline]` test for the key (remembering that params is not a standard hash so testing for keys requires jumping throuigh some small hoops'   The alternative is (as you say) using JS to set a value that's returned.  But the `params[:commit]` is a very common technique and easy to implement.  It also supports localisation if you do it properly so you can set it so that don't care if the button legend changes.

Comment: sorry forgot to tag... above two comments for @nautgrad

Comment: In this case we need to receive true/false from form. I don't see any reason to pollute controller with some logic and 'checks'. Jquery is added to rails by default, so I don't see any reason to ignore it. But if js isn't option, your answer is ok.